# RoR: How to redirect a specific link to sub domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, .htaccess, hyperlink, url-rewriting

In my rails application I have several static and dynamic hyperlinks, programmed in the view as:

```
<%= link_to('Products', products_path) %>
```

This translates to a hyperlink like this:

```
<a href='http://www.mywebsite.com/products'>Products</a>
```

Now, I have published my API docs on subdomain `api.mywebsite.com/api-docs`. How can I program this link in the view so that ALL other links remain on same www root domain.

**Note:** If I set API-Docs link statically like this:

```
<a href='http://api.mywebsite.com/api-docs'>API</a>
```

Then all subsequent links browses on same `api.mywebsite.com` subdomain.

**UPDATE-1:**

API controller for 'products' is located as:

```
./app/controllers/api/v1/products_controller.rb
```

*routes.rb* looks like this after adding constraint.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'pages#index'

  get '/api-docs' => 'pages#api_docs'

  namespace :api, defaults: {format: 'json'} do
    get '/' => '/api#index'
    namespace :v1 do
      get '/' => '/api#index'
      resources :products do
        collection do
          get 'search' => 'products#search', as: :search
        end
      end
    end
  end

  resources :products, :only => [:index, :update, :create]

end
```

Comment: Well, `<...>.path` helper returns "site-root-relative" path and it cannot reflect the domain part. You'll likely need `<...>_url` helpers that return a global one.

Comment: Does it mean replacing _path with _url everywhere in my app ? Will that not cause redirects every time ?

Comment: On server side the picture won't change with either helper, HTTP splits apart request path (`_path` output) and host between different lines. Browsers have no choice but comply :) Still, using `_url` everywhere looks bad, and yet I'm not aware of any alternative.